# EF Migration "baseline script" functionality

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF migrations for several projects and I think it works quite well. However I sometime miss the ability to bundle a set of migrations in order to make a baseline script.

So my question is: Does anyone know of such capability in EF migrations?

Comment: You can delete all the existing migrations and then generate a new migration. this migration will contain all the previous migrations

Comment: @viveknuna That is true but then the database has to be deleted pre-running the migrations. Meaning that the data in the database must be backedup and restored again?

Comment: U have to backup only if you want to apply this migration otherwise not needed

Comment: https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/